# How to add a boolean array to boolean list?

Tags: boolean

I'm trying to do this:

```
    NewRoomate(int studentID, List<Integer> rankedQuestions, boolean...trueFalseQuestions){ 
        this.studentID = studentID;
        this.rankedQuestions = rankedQuestions;
        List<Boolean> wef = Arrays.asList(trueFalseQuestions);
    }
```

But the compiler doesn't like it.
Problems: [image]

How can I convert all of the booleans in the trueFalseQuestions array to a List?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `boolean...trueFalseQuestions` to `Boolean...trueFalseQuestions`

Result will be:

```
NewRoomate(int studentID, List<Integer> rankedQuestions, Boolean...trueFalseQuestions){ 
    this.studentID = studentID;
    this.rankedQuestions = rankedQuestions;
    List<Boolean> wef = Arrays.asList(trueFalseQuestions);
}
```

Comment: Solved so quickly! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
NewRoomate(int studentID, List<Integer> rankedQuestions, Boolean...trueFalseQuestions){ 
        this.studentID = studentID;
        this.rankedQuestions = rankedQuestions;
        List<Boolean> wef = Arrays.asList(trueFalseQuestions);
    }

Just make it to Boolean from boolean.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NewRoomate(int studentID, List<Integer> rankedQuestions, boolean...trueFalseQuestions){ 
        this.studentID = studentID;
        this.rankedQuestions = rankedQuestions;
        List<Boolean> wef = new ArrayList<Boolean>(); //initiate your list
        for(boolean question : trueFalseQuestions){ //fill your list with questions
            wef.add(question);
        }
    }
```